# mysqli alter table rename (to a new database)

Tags: mysqli

I want to move a table ('$bar') from my active database 'foo' to an archive database 'foo_archive'.

I'm doing this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'foo');
```

then:

```
$conn->query("alter table `foo`.`$bar` RENAME `foo_archive`.`$bar`")
```

Strangely, it works, but I get this error message:

```
mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
```

I think that this is beacause I am connected to database 'foo' and not to 'foo_archive'.

I would like to know how to do this properly so as to not receive an error message. I'm also curious as to why it works when, theoretically, I'm not connected to 'foo_archive'.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error message. Only when called procedural style, it expects two parameters; you are using the object oriented style, and that requires only one. Please double-check, that this is actually the part of the code where the error originates.

Comment: [15-May-2016 00:16:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /xxxxxx.php on line 87

Comment: Line 87 MYSQL code: alter table `foo`.`$bar` RENAME `foo_archive`.`$bar`

Comment: @CBroe Is this line wrong? `if (!mysqli_query($conn->query("alter table foo.$bar RENAME foo_archive.$bar"))){/*do something*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $conn->query("alter table `foo`.`$bar` RENAME `foo_archive`.`$bar`")
> ```
>
> Strangely, it works, but I get this error message:
>
> ```
> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
> ```

That code doesn't match the error message. Only when called procedural style, it expects two parameters; you are using the object oriented style, and that requires only one.

[from comments]

> Is this line wrong?
>
> ```
> if (!mysqli_query($conn->query("alter table foo.$bar RENAME foo_archive.$bar"))){...}
> ```

Aha, there we go.

Yes, it is wrong - you are first calling the method the object oriented style (`$conn->query()`), and then you pass the result of that call as an argument into the procedural style call (`mysqli_query()`).

You need to do either of those - not both.

Since you used the OO style already to create the database connection, you should stick to it:

```
if (!$conn->query("alter table foo.$bar RENAME foo_archive.$bar")){...}
```